# Firestore find if a query exists with python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to find if an email already exists in my database when a user signs up. Right now I do:

```py
email = "foo@me.com"
existing_users = db.collection("users").where("email", '==', email).get()
if (len(list(existing_users)):
    print("the user already exists")
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same results?

Comment: What would define "better" in your case?

Comment: I don't know. I come from mongoDB and I'm used to have methods like exists() isEmpty() etc on other databases. This seems a hacked solution, but maybe it's supposed to be this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific query to check if a document exists in Cloud Firestore (although it does exist in Firestore's server-side [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents)). The idiomatic approach is indeed to load the documents (either by ID or with a query) and check if there are any results.